# Не встает Open JDK11 на Windows10

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, jdk11, openjdk

У меня сейчас стоят JDK 1.8.0_192 от Oracle. Решил поставить Open JDK11.
Скачал zip-архив, разархивировал его в C:\Java, далее зашел в свойства ПК - Переменные среды и прописал там в переменной PATH путь к папке bin - C:\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin. Но когда в cmd проверяю версию Java - java -version, мне выдает прежнею версию Java - 1.8.0_192.

Почему?
Что ещё нужно сделать?

Comment: перезапускали консоль?

Comment: да, перезапускал

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir а вы переменные прописали в "Переменные среды пользователя для %name%" или "Системные переменные"?

Comment: и туда, и туда прописал

Comment: у меня ещё в них прописан был вот такой путь - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath". Я его оставил потому что не знаю для чего это

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в символических ссылках  в директории Oracle. Удалил все уставленные ранее Java из программ и из переменных сред (был один путь ведший в Oracle директорию, где были символические ссылки на старые JDK), снова добавил в переменные среды пути к новым jdk - все заработало как надо.